# UNIX 'ls' command - wildcard 'OR' operator

Tags: string, shell, unix, wildcard, ls

I have a directory with timestamped files in the format:

```
processAlpha20120618.txt
processAlpha20120619.txt
processAlpha20120620.txt
processBeta20120618.txt
processBeta20120619.txt
processBeta20120620.txt
... etc.
```

I want a list of these for specific dates. Something like this:

```
ls -l *201206[19|20|21]*
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, but you can see what I was trying to achieve. I want to match anything where the string "201206" is followed by either "19", "20" or "21".

I know that this is possible using **grep** or **find**, I just wondered if it could be done using **ls**.

Comment: As per Ed Heal's answer below, this is a shell issue. So for your information, I'm using Korn shell.

Comment: In KSH, this can be done with `ls -l *201206@(19|20|21)*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls` does not do this - the shell expands `*` etc and then passes them to `ls` as arguments.

Look at the documentation for the shell - it is call [globbing](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/globbingref.html)

Comment: Aha, so it's the shell I need to look at. Thanks for this.

Comment: Well, I looked at the documentation for KSH globbing and found the answer. This can be done with `ls -l *201206@(19|20|21)*`

Comment: @Nossidge This syntax seems to work fine for me in Bash, too.

Answer (score 28):

Providing you're wanting to match exact dates (which it appears you are), the way to so with bash expansion is:

```
ls -l *201206{19,20,21}*
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This is very close to the way KSH does it.